# Docker-compose no such file or directory

Tags: docker, windows10, docker-compose

Estoy intentando montar un proyecto genérico basado en [esta imágen de docker](https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysq) y todo funciona correctamente al crear los contenedores y lanzarlos, la base de datos es accesible desde **PHPMyAdmin** y el **PHP** se lanza correctamente.

El problema viene cuando intento hacer una conexion con la base de datos. Se debe a un problema de permisos sobre el volumen que se monta `- ./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`. Al intentar realizar una conexión en un **PHP** me lanza el error `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in`

La conexión la estoy haciendo tal que así:

```
$conn =  new mysqli(
    $settings['db_host'],
    $settings['db_username'],
    $settings['db_password'],
    $settings['db_name']
);`
```

Lo poco que he encontrado menciona algo de permisos; si bien parece ser que al intentar realizar la conexión con la **BBDD** se necesita permiso de escritura sobre ese directorio. Tambien he leido que hay algun problema con **PHP-FPM** y los permisos con **Docker**.

Este es mi **docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
            - "./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "./etc/ssl:/etc/ssl"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
            - "./etc/nginx/default.template.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template"
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
            - "3000:443"
        environment:
            - NGINX_HOST=${NGINX_HOST}
        command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysqldb
    php:
        image: nanoninja/php-fpm
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "./etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
    composer:
        image: "composer"
        volumes:
            - "./web/app:/app"
        command: install
    myadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - mysqldb
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql
        container_name: ${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - ".env"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - "8989:3306"
        volumes:
            - "./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"`
```

Quizás lo mas importante viene ahora, la maquina docker funciona en Windows 10 PRO con **HyperV** y una VMachine con **Alpine Linux v3.5.**

Comment: Eso es raro, ¿haces una conexión PDO y el fallo es con MySQLi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado el problema, se trata de un error sintáctico a la hora de hacer la conexion mediante mysqli. El nombre del host debe ser exactamente el mismo nombre que le hayamos dado al servicio en el archivo docker-compose. En mi caso, el servicio que lanza el contenedor mysql se llama **mysqldb**, por tanto la conexión debe ser tal que así:

```
$conn =  new mysqli(
        'mysqldb', #Importante poner al host el mismo nombre que el servicio
        'db_username',
        'db_password',
        'db_name'
    );
```